# Generalizing the Notion of Nilpotent/Abelian/Cyclic Numbers

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

Let us call a number $n\in\mathbb{N}$ *nilpotent* if

$$n=p_1^{e_1}\cdots p_m^{e_m}$$

with $p_i^k\not\equiv 1\mod p_j$ for $i,j\in\{1,\ldots,m\}$ and $1\leqslant k\leqslant e_i$.

A cute theorem says the following:

> **Theorem:** *Every group of order $n$ is nilpotent, if and only if $n$ is a nilpotent number.*

But, the interesting thing is that the theorem doesn't stop there. It also says the following:

> **Theorem:** *Every group of order $n$ is abelian, if and only if $n$ is a cubefree nilpotent number.*
>
> **Theorem:** *Every group of order $n$ is cyclic, if and only if $n$ is a squarefree nilpotent number.*

For this reason squarefree and cubefree nilpotent numbers are called *cyclic* and *abelian* respectively.

The proofs of these theorems can be found [here](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2589118).

There is, of course, after hearing these last two theorems an obvious question: what does being a nilpotent number indivisible by an $\ell^{\text{th}}$ power, for $\ell\geqslant 4$ correspond to? In particular, one might guess that there is some filtration of classes of groups

$$C_2\subseteq C_3\subseteq C_4\subseteq\cdots\subseteq\{\text{nilpotent groups}\}$$

where all groups of order $n$ are in $C_\ell$ if and only if $n$ is a nilpotent number not divisible by an $\ell^{\text{th}}$-power.

For example, we have already remarked that

$$C_1=\{\text{cyclic groups}\}\qquad C_2=\{\text{abelian groups}\}$$

Also, if we can find such classes $C_j$, is there some unifying, governing statistic of groups naturally indexed by $\mathbb{N}$, for which $C_j$ is just the class of groups satisfying the $j^{\text{th}}$ statistic?

Thanks!

Comment: Since the paper you cite also characterizes solvable numbers, maybe you can extend your filtration and numbering scheme accordingly.  And perhaps even incorporate "p-group numbers".

Comment: The JSTOR link has sadly gone stale... where is this paper located?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A nilpotent group is the direct product of its Sylow subgroups, hence the nilpotency class of a nilpotent group equals the maximum of the nilpotency classes of its Sylow subgroups. A group of order $p^n$ has nilpotency class at most n-1, since if $G/G'$ was cyclic, then $G$ itself would be cyclic. On the other hand, $p$-groups of maximal class do exist, so we obtain that for $n\geq 2$, $C_n$ consists precisely of the nilpotent groups of class $\leq n-1$, while $C_1$ is the class of cyclic groups.

Comment: Thank you :) In retrospect, that should have been pretty obvious!

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/a/67469/589.