# On group varieties and numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory, gr.group-theory, finite-groups, universal-algebra

Suppose $\mathfrak{U}$ is a group variety. Let’s define $N_{\mathfrak{U}} \subset \mathbb{N}$ as a such set of numbers, that for any finite group $G$, $|G| \in N_{\mathfrak{U}}$ implies $G \in \mathfrak{U}$.

Examples:

If $\mathfrak{O}$ is the variety of all groups, then $N_{\mathfrak{O}} = \mathbb{N}$.

If $\mathfrak{B}_m$ is the variety of all groups of exponent dividing $m$, then $N_{\mathfrak{B}_m}$ is the set of all divisors of $m$

If $\mathfrak{N}_c$ is the variety of all groups of nilpotency class $c$ or less, then $N_{\mathfrak{N}_c}$ is the set of all numbers $n=p_1^{e_1}\cdots p_m^{e_m}$ with $p_i^k\not\equiv 1\pmod {p_j}$ for $i,j\in\{1,\ldots,m\}$ and $1\leqslant k\leqslant e_i$, and $e_i \leq c + 1$ for $i\in\{1,\ldots,m\}$.

If $\mathfrak{U}$ and $\mathfrak{V}$ are two varieties, then $N_{\mathfrak{U}\cap\mathfrak{V}} = N_{\mathfrak{U}} \cap N_{\mathfrak{V}}$

My question is:

> Does there exist some number-theoretic characterisation of all such subsets $N \subset \mathbb{N}$, such that $N = N_{\mathfrak{U}}$ for some variety $\mathfrak{U}$?

Any $N_{\mathfrak{U}}$ satisfies the property:

> If $a \in N_{\mathfrak{U}}$ and $b | a$, then $b \in N_{\mathfrak{U}}$

Suppose $|G| = b$ and $G \notin \mathfrak{U}$. Then $G \times C_{\frac{a}{b}} \notin \mathfrak{U}$.

> If $\exists n \in \mathbb{N}$, such that $\forall k \in \mathbb{N}$ $n^k \in N_{\mathfrak{U}}$, then $\mathfrak{U} = \mathfrak{O}$.

By previous lemma, we can assume without loss of generality, that $n = p$ is prime. The only variety, that contains all $p$-groups for a fixed prime $p$ is $\mathfrak{O}$

However, I am not sure, whether those two conditions are sufficient to characterise all such sets or not.

This question was inspired by [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/143653/110691)

[I also asked it on MSE a month ago, but received no answer to my original question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3290810/407165)

Comment: @YCor, by the variety of groups of nilpotency class $c$ I meant the variety defined by the law $[[...[x_1, x_2], x_3]...], x_c] = 1$ which in fact contains all groups of nilpotency class $c$ or less.

Comment: @YCor, also I would like to note, that $N_{\mathfrak{U}}$ is the defined as the set of such numbers, that **ALL** groups, whose orders lie in $N_{\mathfrak{U}}$ are from $\mathfrak{U}$.

Comment: Ah OK, I misunderstood, erased my comment.